# How to correctly scale a background image

Tags: css

I've got a 8192x8192 image which should be used as a background image. It shows the image but only the half and I've got no clue how to scale the height correctly.

My CSS code:

```
body {
background: url('../img/atlas.png') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: make it the background of the body instead

Comment: then it won't scale correctly. its just showing in my case 1920x1080 of the image. but not the whole picture

Comment: because you used cover, what you need is contain or `100% 100%`

Comment: ```body {
    background-image: url('../img/atlas.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}```
now i've got it all on my body. but its small and covers not the whole screen

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%` not height/width

Comment: now it scales the width correctly, but not the height.

Comment: you need to know what you want then ... check the documentation of background size and see all the possible value you can put and try them until you get want you need

Comment: I want it to scale it fullscreen and it does not work with the height.

Comment: Your problem is you don't really know how images work on the web, you can either have an image that covers the entire screen and in doing so may cut off your image, or have a full image that may not cover the entire screen. You cant have both.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```css
body {
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/IvfoDk30JnI/1500x1000) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```